How to calculate the average stream velocity from the segmentation of video frames?
I have a 10 second video of a river flowing. I want to calculate the velocity of the river flow using optical flow. In this operation, I used the ImageDisplacements command. Can someone help me calculate the average velocity numerically.
The commands are as follows:
Importing video and dividing frames
vid = Import["video\\river.mp4"];
part = VideoExtractFrames[vid, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}];
imgta = ImageTake[#, -1600] & /@ part;
re = ImageResize[#, {300, 300}] & /@ imgta;

In order to display the particles better, we used the binarize command.
bin = Binarize[#, Method -> "Mean"] & /@ re


Using the ImageDisplacements command to calculate displacement in each image.
flow = Mean@ImageDisplacements[Append[bin, bin[[1]]]]

listCurl =
  flow |-> 
   ListConvolve[{{0.5, 0, -0.5}}, 
     flow[[All, All, 2]], {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, "Fixed"] - 
    ListConvolve[{{-0.5}, {0}, {0.5}}, 
     flow[[All, All, 1]], {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, "Fixed"];
curl = ImageAdjust@Image@GaussianFilter[listCurl@flow, 8 {3, 3}]


Then display the most displacement.
ImageCompose[re[[1]], 
 SetAlphaChannel[
  Colorize[curl, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}]], 
  ColorNegate[curl]]]



Please don't delete a question, then post the same one. Now I have to repeat my comment: I don't really think this is a Mathematica question. Mathematica is a software which will do what you tell it to do. But you don't even have an "algorithm" for determining the flow velocity from the video yet ... What is your strategy?

There doesn't seem to be any objects flowing with the water which you could use for tracking. And the water surface seems to turbulent and jerky, so I don't think you can track the sun reflections ... I suggest you first find an appropriate algorithm you want to use (e.g. optical flow water surface).

Is it possible to calculate the water velocity by moving the vectors caused by moves the bubbles or waves in the direction of the flow? What is meant by strategy?
